# Возможно ли удалить пустой коммит из истории гитхаб?

Tags: git, github

Весь вопрос в названии. У меня несколько таких коммитов из за какого-то тупого слияния: Showing 0 changed files with 0 additions and 0 deletions.

Казалось простейший вопрос, однозначного ответа я не нашёл, то гит rebase то reset то ещё хрен пойми что.

Comment: Гит позволяет сделать с историей комитов что угодно. Я как-то в комитах подменял адреса почты - ребята попросили чтобы их коммерческие адреса не торчали в опенсорсе. Это можно, но сложно и рисковано - можно все стереть напрочь. Слияние совсем не тупое, пустыми комитами гит напоминает сам себе и вам что все изменения из побочной ветки учтены в основной - например, они осознано отвергнуты. Об этом тоже нужна отметка в истории.